# Removing duplicates code debugging

Tags: python, python-3.x

As a newbie python programmer, I've been doing some exercises, but I don't understand why this code will not work for me.

Now my exercise is this:

> Define and test a function named removeDuplicates(somelist) that removes all duplicates from a given list and returns the remaining elements as a list while keeping the original order. Also define a main() function that calls on the removeDuplicates function for the given command line argument and prints the resulting list.

And here is my code so far:

```
import sys

def main():
    userInput = int(input(""))
    removeDuplicates(somelist)
    print (unique)

def removeDuplicates(userInput):
    duplicate = set()
    unique = []   
    for x in userInput:
        if x not in duplicate:
            unique.append(x)
            duplicate.add(x)

    print (unique)

def removeDuplicates(somelist):
    duplicate = set()
    unique = [] 
    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if x not in sys.stdin:
            unique.append(x)
            duplicate.add(x)

    return unique

if __name__ =='__main__':
    main()
```

And I keep getting error codes no matter what I do. The error code for this code is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "removeDuplicates.py", line 31, in <module>
main()
File "removeDuplicates.py", line 5, in main
removeDuplicates(somelist)
NameError: name 'somelist' is not defined`
```

Comment: Could you fix the indentation? The code as posted throws syntax/indentation errors.

Comment: Were the syntax errors caused by the incorrect indentation? I wonder if this question needs to be closed as "non-reproducible or typo".

Answer (score 1):

You are not declared the `somelist`, It may be like this,

```
......
userInput = int(input(""))
removeDuplicates(userInput)
......
```

Answer (score 0):

This code simply prints the unique values list:

```
def main():
    userInput = input("Enter an integers, separated by spaces(' '):").split()
    unique = removeDuplicates(userInput)
    print(unique)

def removeDuplicates(userInput):
    unique = []
    for i in userInput:
        if i not in unique:
            unique.append(i)
    return unique

if __name__ =='__main__':
    main()
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: But importing sys module is not necessary.

Comment: Would you edit this answer to describe what you changed and why? That might be useful for future readers, who won't immediately see what your strategy was.